# How to access the indexer with Interface Explicitly implemended

Tags: c#

When we explicitly implement an interface for an indexer, how can we able to set and get value form the indexer after creating object. or inside the same class constructor

```
namespace oopsTesting.Indexer
{
    public interface IndexerInterface
    {
        char this[int index] { get; set;}
    }

    class Indexer : IndexerInterface
    {
        string name = "Babu Kumarasamy";
        StringBuilder sbName = new StringBuilder("Babu Kumarasamy");

        public Indexer()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sbName.Length; i++)
            {
                //How to access the indexer here
                Console.WriteLine("Property Indexer: {0}, StringBuilder: {1}", this[i], sbName[i]);
            }
        }
        char IndexerInterface.this[int index]
        {
            get { return name[index]; }

            set
            {
                //Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
                //Strings are immutable which is why there's no setter, you can however use a string builder:
                //name[index] = value; 

                sbName[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GenericIndexerTest objGenIndexer = new GenericIndexerTest();
            //How to access the indexer here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The *very first* Google result for "explicit interface implementation" is [Explicit Interface Implementation Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which answers your question.

Comment: cast this to the interface                                                 Console.WriteLine("Property Indexer: {0}, StringBuilder: {1}", ((IndexerInterface)this)[i], sbName[i]);

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of `Indexer`, assigning it to a variable of type `IndexerInterface`:

```
IndexerInterface ii = new Indexer();
char c = ii[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This answer assumes `GenericIndexerTest` inherits `Indexer` in your code)

The same way as you access *any* explicitly implemented interface, by casting to the interface type:

```
GenericIndexerTest objGenIndexer = new GenericIndexerTest();
((IndexerInterface)objGenIndexer)[0] = 'A';
```

or code to the interface, not the implementation:

```
IndexerInterface objGenIndexer = new GenericIndexerTest();
objGenIndexer[0] ='A';
```